# I have valid h1b but my passport is expired in USA. Can I work at clients location legally? I have applied for renewal of my passport.

Tags: immigration, indian-citizens, passport, h1-visa

My Indian passport is currently expired and I have valid h1b until Aug , 2018. As per I 9 , am I legally eligible to work at clients location?

Comment: To be specific, when you say "valid H-1b", do you mean a valid H-1b petition, or a valid I-94?

Answer (score 2):

The [I-9 instructions](https://www.uscis.gov/system/files_force/files/form/i-9instr.pdf) do not say anything about the validity of the passport.  As long as your I-94 is valid, and it is endorsed such that you are permitted to work for that client, you should be fine.

Comment: Specifically, an H-1b I-94 without a valid passport is a [List C document](https://www.uscis.gov/i-9-central/acceptable-documents/list-documents/form-i-9-acceptable-documents?topic_id=1&t=c), which needs to be used with a List B document (a valid ID) for I-9 purposes; whereas an H-1b I-94 with a valid passport would be a List A document.

Answer (score -1):

Documents that Establish Both Identity and Employment Authorization

**For a nonimmigrant alien authorized to work for a specific employer because of his or her status:**

1. Foreign passport; and
2. An endorsement of the alien's nonimmigrant status as long as that period of endorsement has not yet expired and the proposed employment is not in conflict with any restrictions or limitations identified on the form.